# Rigid body joints 'popping out'

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation

I am attempting to make a building framework using rigid bodies but the simulation doesn't seem to be using the mesh correctly. I have two beams arranged in a joint and have made sure them meshes do not intersect. However, when I start the simulations they 'pop' outwards as if they are overlapping and need to move away from each other. I have included a gif of the first few frames as well as the rigid body settings for the beams.

[image: Beam pop]
[image: Rigid body settings]

Comment: You need to set Rigid Body Collisions Shape to Mesh, Convex Hull is something like a bounding box and your parts won't fit in each other.

Comment: Ive tried setting the shape to mesh and the margin to 0.0 but i get the same issue. The source is set to deform.